# Loopback address set for facebook and youtube

Tags: networking, dns, ping, youtube, localhost

I have Windows 7 laptop.
I can not access facebook and youtube. It is a office laptop and Symantec Antivirus is installed with centralize management. 
If I ping both the site like : ping www.youtube.com or ping www.facebook.com It refers to 127.0.0.1

C:\Windows\System32>ping www.facebook.com

Pinging www.facebook.com [127.0.0.1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

In Host file I have checked it does not have entries for both sites.(no entry at-all)
Is there any other location to specify these ips for these sites?

Answer (score 1):

If it is a office laptop, can it be that your employer has banned those websites? Try to ask colleagues to ping to youtube. If they have the same problem, it could be that someone in your company has made a permanent entry in the local DNS-server that youtube and facebook will be resolved to 127.0.0.1.

Final Solution: As a workaround, you can make an entry for both websites in your host file. So '173.252.110.27 www.facebook.com' and next line '173.194.65.93 www.youtube.com'. Try if you are able to reach www.youtube.com or www.facebook.com after that. Apart from that, you can also try to use another browser and restart your pc just as part of common issue-solving.

Comment: Other colleagues can access these site. And my office desktop engineers are not able to answer this question. my employed have not blocked these sites; and most important even if i am not loged-in on my employer network and I am using data card still laptop behaves ex explained above.

Comment: Try to clear your dns cache with the command ´ipconfig /flushdns´. Or do you have a device in tethering mode? If so, disconnect that tablet, smartphone or device and try again to run ´ipconfig /flushdns´ and then try to access Youtube or Facebook

Comment: ipconfig /flushdns did not worked. and laptop is not in tethering mode.

Comment: As a workaround, you can make an entry for both websites in your host file. So '173.252.110.27 www.facebook.com' and next line '173.194.65.93 www.youtube.com'. Try if you are able to reach www.youtube.com or www.facebook.com after that. Apart from that, you can also try to use another browser and restart your pc just as part of common issue-solving.

Comment: Thank you very much Dave. adding entry to host file worked. Google IPs keep changing I have tried this solution for ip 74.125.236.41; but that time it did not worked.
Actually I want to access videos on https://aws.amazon.com/ which embedds youtube video.
But your trick worked. I can see these videos now.

Comment: Nice that it is working! Could you mark my answer as best answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A creative but not very effective way to block websites. They are probably messing with the DNS. Try running the command `nslookup www.facebook.com 8.8.8.8`, this will give you a list of IP addresses for facebook. If it does not work on your laptop try it on another computer. Once you have an IP address simply create a bookmark in your browser using the IP as the address.

Some advice: if they are making efforts to block those sites they will make efforts to punish you if they find out you're circumventing the block.

Comment: Yup, it's almost certainly a policy block.  Go to a coffee shop down the street if you want to surf Facebook.  ;-)